# How to compute frequency via list comprehension?

Tags: list, haskell

```
count :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Int
count n [] = 0
count n (x:xs) | n == x = 1 + count n xs
           | otherwise = count n xs



rmdups :: Eq a => [a] -> [a]
rmdups [ ] = [ ]
rmdups (x:xs) = x : rmdups (filter(/= x) xs)
```

using the 2 functions, a third needs to be created, called frequency:
it should count how many times each distinct value in a list occurs in that list. for example : frequency "ababc", should return [(3,'a'),(2,'b'),(1,'c')].
the layout for frequency is :

```
frequency :: Eq a => [a] -> [(Int, a)]
```

P.s rmdups, removes duplicates from list, so rmdups "aaabc" = abc
and count 2 [1,2,2,2,3] = 3.

so far i have:

```
frequency :: Eq a => [a] -> [(Int, a)]
frequency [] = []
frequency (x:xs) = (count x:xs, x) : frequency (rmdups xs)
```

but this is partly there, (wrong). thanks

Comment: [Run length encoding in Haskell](http://donsbot.wordpress.com/2007/07/31/run-length-encoding-in-haskell/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
frequency xs = map (\c -> (count c xs,c)) (rmdups xs)
```

or, with a list comprehension,

```
frequency xs = [(count c xs, c) | c <- rmdups xs]
```

is the shortest way to define it using your `count` and `rmdups`. If you need it sorted according to frequency (descending) as in your example,

```
frequency xs = sortBy (flip $ comparing fst) $ map (\c -> (count c xs,c)) (rmdups xs)
```

using `sortBy` from `Data.List` and `comparing` from `Data.Ord`.

If all you have is an `Eq` constraint, you cannot gain much efficiency, but if you only need it for types in `Ord`, you can get a much more efficient implementation using e.g. `Data.Set` or `Data.Map`.

Comment: sorry , but can you lease also help me to define it only using list comprehension please, thanks, beuase im not sure of how to use the lambda function, \ at all. thanks

Comment: Sure, list comprehension added.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my own 'lazy' answer, which does not call rmdups:

```
frequency [] = []
frequency (y:ys) = [(count y (y:ys), y)] ++ frequency (filter (/= y) ys)
```

Answer (score 0):

`import qualified Data.Set as Set`

`frequency xs = map (\x -> (length $ filter (== x) xs, x)) (Set.toList $ Set.fromList xs)`